# Trying to display jpg images from URLs, copied exact script from answers to previous questions on same subject, still getting errors

Tags: excel, image, url, jpeg, display

```
# Reading an excel file using Python
import xlrd
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import Image
from skimage import io
from io import BytesIO

# Give the location of the file
loc = ("F://Documents//Bridges//URLs.xlsx")

# To open Workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

# input is requested and stored in a variable
row_start = input('Row Number =  ')

# convert user input into an integer
x = int(row_start)

# Find URL
image_url = sheet.cell_value(x,0)

# Print URl
print (image_url)

#Buffer image as described in earlier answer to same question
response = urlopen('image_url')
buf = BytesIO(response.read())
im = Image.open(buf)
a = io.Image(im)

#Display image    
io.imshow(a)
io.show()

# I get the following errors
#File "C:/Users/Wayne/PycharmProjects/untitled/URls2.py", line 29, in <module>
#   response = urlopen('image_url')
#  File "C:\Users\Wayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222,
```

in urlopen
    #    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    #  File "C:\Users\Wayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 509, 
in open
    #    req = Request(fullurl, data)
    #  File "C:\Users\Wayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 328, 
in **init**
    #    self.full_url = url
    #  File "C:\Users\Wayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 354, 
in full_url
    #    self._parse()
    #  File "C:\Users\Wayne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 383, in _parse
    #    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
    #ValueError: unknown url type: 'image_url'

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using another simpler method.  Please don't spend time trying to solve this one.  I really appreciate the help from this community and do not want to abuse the privilege.